# If there was a memory leak in a Java program would it show a high memory usage in the task bar

Tags: java, class, memory, task, memory-leaks

Can I quickly assess whether a program running on JBoss server has a memory leak if the java.exe process in the Task Manager has an unusual high amount of memory usage (i.e. 1,443,984K)?

Comment: Is the amount of memory it's using increasing?

Comment: No, but constantly increasing memory usage should make you suspicious at least.

Comment: What kind of memory usage measurement was this? Resident set? Commit charge? Virtual memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to debug suspected memoryy leaks in Java is to take a heap dump and use IBM's HeapAnalyzer.  Take a look at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21190608

Answer (score 0):

You can have a closer look at the heap using for example [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html). High memory usage is not necessarily an indication for a leak, but steadily increasing memory usage along with frequent garbage collections that reclaim almost no memory might be.

Answer (score 0):

High Memory usage shown in task manager for java.exe does not necessarily suggest a memory leak. Whereas a continuously increasing memory usage does relate to a memory leak.
Here is a good article about memory leak, how to analyse and fix them and which tools can be used: 
http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/